# Facebook Mobile API.

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Is it possible to track your Facebook notifications through an app other than Facebook's? I am looking to track the photos tagged of a person in facebook through an app.

Comment: Don't think this is possible. Notifications go to the actual FaceBook app and I don't think you will have access to that app to get the notifications from it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no. The Facebook sdk offers `/user/notifications` [as an edge](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user) through the Graph API. That, however, requires the `manage_notifications` token [which is unavailable](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-manage_notifications) to all Android, iOS, Web, and TV apps.

For your application, though, you're in luck (or at least I think you are). If you are trying to access all the photos of your user, you can use `/user/photos` to retrieve all the [photos](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos/) that the user is tagged in. If you follow the [Reference Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/photos/), it'll give you back 25 photos. In order to grab more, and to 'page' through the data, use the `limit` and `offset` parameters as follows

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("limit","400");
params.putString("offset","800");
new Request( Session.getActiveSession(),
     "/me/likes",
     params,
     HttpRequest.GET,
     new RequestCallback() {
          // handle results here
     }
).executeAsync();
```

This request should give you all the information you need to know about the photo, but be sure to check out [the documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/photo) to get a list of all the fields available.

As a side note, you can also access [albums](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/album) to retrieve photos that the user has posted, which will also contain tagging information.